# How do you pass Content-Type header when testing Silex REST service?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, silex

I'm testing a Silex REST service as explained [here](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/testing.html) but also trying to automatically decode JSON data as is also explained [in the manual](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html) but somehow it fails to create the $data parameter.

In my test I'm calling the service with:

```
$data = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/resources/billing-info.json');
$client->request('POST', '/users/test_user/bills',array(), array(), array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'), $data);
```

and in the Controller I try to access the unmarshalled data as

```
$app->post('/users/{username}/bills', function(Request $request, $username) use($app) {
try {
   $myData = $request->data;
   .....
} catch (Exception $e){
   return $app->json(array('error'=>$e->getMessage()),$e->getCode());
}
});
```

But the $data is non existent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `Content-Type` to `CONTENT_TYPE`. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/BrowserKit/blob/9b36e22ede8b6c965aba28e0e5d0a88c6822d1fb/Client.php#L289) for the Client class, you'll find that the `$server` argument needs to match the keys given by the $_SERVER superglobal. The content-type header is stored in the `CONTENT_TYPE` key.

```
$client->request('POST', '/users/test_user/bills',array(), array(), array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'), $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Documentation on the [Request-Object](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html). I guess instead of `$myData = $request->data;` it must be:

```
$myData = $request->getContent();
```